# помогите, пжл, код подправить

Tags: javascript

пользователь вводит в форму число - на экран должны вывести столько же квадратов, которые при наведении курсора меняют цвет, не могу прикрепить корректно квадрат к переменной

```js
var nomer = prompt('write a number', '');
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var nomer = document.getElementById("b");
  innerHTML = '';
}
```

```css
div {
 width: 70px; height: 70px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 5px;
}
div:hover { background: #ff9f19; }
.b { background: black; }
.r { background: #009abf; }
```

```html
<div class="b"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var number = prompt('write a number', '');
var parent = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
  var square = document.createElement('div');
  square.classList.add('b');
  parent.appendChild(square);
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

div:hover {
  background: #ff9f19;
}

.b {
  background: black;
}

.r {
  background: #009abf;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Создать элемент:

```
let div = document.createElement ("div")
```

добавить элемент в `<body>`

```
document.body.append(div)
```

Все вместе:

```js
var count = prompt('squares count','');
for (i=0; i<+count; i++) {
   let div = document.createElement ("div");
   document.body.append(div);
}
```

```css
 div {
    width: 70px; 
    height: 70px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background: black;
 }
 div:hover { 
   background: #ff9f19;
 }
```